# HTML Progressive running number like Jackpot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wan to create something like the jackpot progressive same like the sample picture.

[image: SampleOutput]

The number will time to time looping.
May i know how can i create something like that. 
Any suggestion or sample on that ?
Can be javascript or jquery.

Comment: Can you explain how the jackpot works?

Comment: You mean you want to know how to animate each digit to roll upwards? (I'd be surprised if there isn't already a jQuery plugin that does that.) Or would a reasonable starting place just be to update the value every x milliseconds without animation?

Comment: @nnnnnn i wish to know that how to do and change the number every second as well. As i not expert in web platform, i need an idea or if got sample on doing this will be easy for me to understand.

Comment: @RahulRavindran i wan to do something like every second trigger a function to do API call and get a value make the number changing in every second. Something like the jackpot progressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a progressive jackpot using `jquery`. There is a [plugin](https://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html) that already does that.

You can either generate a random number as a result or check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/) to see how you could end with specific number everytime. (Like a number generated from an api)

Edit : In case you are looking for simple Counting up check [CountUp.js](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)

Comment: thanks for your sample , but this one is more on slot game method right ? it will be random running and stop at the result.
But what i need is slowly increase number by number one.

Comment: Increase in an order? like counting up?

Comment: it like now the value = 1000  then new value = 1200 then it will running from 1000 to 1200 just like the sample picture.

Comment: I have editted the answer with counting up plugin. You can customize it to your preference using css. Please accept the answer it that helps you.

Comment: i think this sample will close to what i need . Thank for your help !